# Standard Mapper and Reducer Classes for Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, spring-batch, spring-data

Is there a package or a collection of standard Mappers and Reducers for Hadoop?

for example, OpenMP comes with a predefined set of reducers for the parallelization of loops, which comes in handy, but is not extendable. A similar set of basic reducers would be handy for Hadoop.

When you build Spring Batch Applications with Spring-Data Hadoop, such a set would be really useful.

If there is no such a thing we could start a collection.

Kr, R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop comes with a large set of Mappers and Reducers included. They're stored in `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib`, and cover a wide variety of use cases. If you want to see a quick list, [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/) is the `mapred.lib` javadocs web UI. Give it a look and see if any of those fit your need.

Comment: Hi! Looks like the right thing, I will take a look at it.
Thanks!

P.s.: @all links to other collections are still appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [github project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-hadoop).  I've never used it, but it claims to have spring and hadoop stuff in it.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with this one. It's the official repository of http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/hadoop

It's a sub project of spring data

You could add a spring-data-hadoop tag to Stackoverflow, which seems to be the fitting thing for this library (it's still kinda new, but usefull)